# Convert CURL command to URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a curl command in order to use it within swift for an ios app i'm making. I'm using a playground project to try out this feature.

The curl command is as follows:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://myurl.com/mydata' \-H 'x-api-key: xxx' \-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \-d '{"uniqueNumber": “F4”}’
```

When I enter this into terminal, my data is displayed.

I have browsed through stackoverflow and managed to find articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929740/convert-curl-command-to-http-request-in-swift) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779004/convert-curl-to-urlrequest)

I'm still fairly new to swift and from what I understand, curl does not work in swift and so you have to convert it to a URLRequest.

I have attempted this with my code below but keep getting a message that says "Missing Authentication Token". What am I doing wrong?

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let key = "xxx"
let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/mydata")
let contentType = "application/json"
let uniqueNumber = "F4"
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

request.addValue("x-api-key: \(key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "-H")
request.addValue("Content-Type: \(contentType)", forHTTPHeaderField: "-H")
request.addValue("uniqueNumber: \(uniqueNumber)", forHTTPHeaderField: "-d")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }

    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}

task.resume()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

- update -

Found the issue. I had to include the requestHTTP method, as well as the httpBody. After doing this it was fully working. See below for the working code:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let key = "xxx"
let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/mydata")
let contentType = "application/json"

//setting and converting the uniqueNumber (input) to a data item so it can be recognized by the API

var uniqueNumber: Data? = "{\"uniqueNumber\": \"F09\"}".data(using: .utf8) // non-nil

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = uniqueNumber

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
}.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set header like this...

```
request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(uniqueNumber, forHTTPHeaderField: "uniqueNumber")
```

You were setting invalid headers for a request.

**EDIT**

You also need to add *Authentication Token* in header like below.

```
let authToken = "THIS IS AUTHENTICATION TOKEN TO BE PASSED ON SERVER"
request.addValue(authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "authenticationToken")

//Please make sure to pass the authentication token the key "authenticationToken". 
//Please change as per actual key to be passed
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have changed my headers according to your instructions but I still seem to get the same error message "Missing Authentication Token"

Comment: I've added the authToken as per your edit. I'm not sure what my token is as I only have an API key to communicate with this API. I set the authToken as my API Key and still get the same error. However when I changed the authenticationToken headerfield to "Authorization" i get a much longer message: "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=xxx" I don't know any of these :/